# Combining similar values in a single column

Tags: sql

I have a column that is being used to list competitors names in a table I'm putting together.  Right now don't have a lot of control over how these inputs are made, and it causes some serious headaches.  There are random spaces and misspellings throughout our data, and yet we need to list the data by competitor.

As an example (not actual SQL I'm using), list of competitors:

```
Price Cutter
PriceCutter
PriceCuter
Price Cuter
```

If I ran the query:

```
SELECT Competitor_Name, SUM(Their_Sales),
FROM Cmdata.Competitors
Where Their_Sales
Between 10000 AND 100000000
Group by Competitor_Name
```

I would get a different entry for each version of Price Cutter, something I clearly want to avoid.

I would think this problem would come up a lot, but I did a Google search and came up dry.  I will admit, the question is kind of hard to articulate in a few words, maybe that's why I didn't come with anything.  Either that or this is so basic I should already know...

(PS- Yes, we're moving to a drop down menu, but it's gonna take some time.  In the mean time, is there a solution?)

Comment: The term that you're looking for is *fuzzy matching*.  How you would do this depends on what RBDMS you're using.  Like the answers suggest, its probably easier to just clean your data than it would be to try to implement something like a [levenshtein distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) using Sql.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted what I'm using. It's DB2 for i (IBM).  I use SQL to get into it and pull data out, but I only have read access.  Anything I would do to clean up data would involve me pulling down the data and then correcting it myself.  Other fixes would need to go through IS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `Competitor` table, that has a standard name for each competitor.

Then, use foreign key references in other tables.

The problem that you are facing is a data cleansing and data modeling issue.  It is not particularly hard to solve, but it does require a fair amount of work.  You can get started by getting a list of all the current spellings and standardize them -- probably in an Excel spreadsheet.

If you do that, you can then create a lookup table and change the values by looking them up.

However, in the medium term, you should be creating a `Competitor` table and modelling the data in the way that your application needs.

Comment: So...  In essence I need to make a list of all the competitors (their proper names) and set up foreign keys to connect misspellings with their proper spelling in that second table?

Comment: No, no no.  Set up a table with the proper spellings and a numeric primary key.  Put the primary key in the table you are using (or, the proper name, if you cannot change the structure of the table).  The problem is creating the mapping.  You need the misspellings for the mapping.

Comment: I only have read access to the table, actually.  Though I suppose I could just offload it and try what you're saying.

Comment: @JayCarr . . . In that case, build the mapping table and join to it, if you have permissions.  You can fix the problem at query time doing a join or by updating the value to the consistent naming value.

Comment: I do have permission to create a join between separate DBs so that should be fine.  Kinda new, is this what you're asking me to do?   I would need to create some tables on my computer.  One would contain misspelled names and another table would have proper names and a numeric key.  Then on the table with the misspelled names, use the numeric value from the properly spelled table as a foreign key.  Then do a join that pulls the main table together with the misspelled table together with the correctly spelled table.  Then Group By the correctly spelled names in the resulting table, right?

Comment: @JayCarr . . . That seems like a good idea.  You can use a `left outer join` and keep the existing value if it doesn't match.  The additional table then acts like an override table on the values.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very hard problem in general. If your database supports it, you could try grouping by `SOUNDEX(Competitor_Name)` instead of just `Competitor_Name`.

Really, the `Competitor_Name` column should be a foreign key into a `Competitors` table anyway, instead of a bare text field.

Whatever you do to fix, you should also UPDATE the table so that you don't have to do this sort of hoop-jumping in the future.

Comment: I like this response (just because the tech sounds cool) but unfortunately it's not accurate enough.  It's combining distinctly different people together because they sound the same.  Might be useful as part of a bigger clean up effort though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm a bit hazy on the syntax, but this is close)

```
alter table Competitors add column cleanedName (varchar(100));

update Competitors set cleanedName = Replace(Upper(Competitor_Name), ' ', '')
```

then Group by cleanedName instead of Competitor_Name

Comment: Ah, so that should at least get ride of any spaces I don't want, okay, that's a step in the right direction at least.  A good first step, if you will.

Comment: I'm assuming I could also use this to replace '-' with '', right?  (Yeah, I know, I'll try it... I get lazy sometimes.)